# While loop doesn't show?

Tags: php

I am trying to write out all the array values using a `while` loop but it isn't working, any tips?

```
$console = array("Wii","Playstation 3","Xbox","Dator");
echo "I like " .$console[0] . " and " . $console[1] . ".";

while($console <5){
    echo "The console you like is: $console <br>";
    $x++;
}
```

My first `echo` is visible but the second one in my loop is not, what have I done wrong? The `while` loop should be able to show all 4 consoles variables but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: 1) Your while loop is an infinite loop as $console never changes 2) $console is an array so checking that it's less than 5 doesn't make sense. 3) You should be using foreach instead of while.

Comment: `while(count($console) < 5){}` maybe

Comment: or from php manual: `while (list ($key, $val) = each ($console) ) 
  echo $val."<br/>";`

Comment: now u have few solutions, did u tried?

Comment: yeah i tried them all! 
thanks for the help i understand the code much better now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your desired output by using `foreach()` and no need to use any extra function like `count()`

**Example:**

```
$console = array("Wii","Playstation 3","Xbox","Dator");
foreach ($console as $key => $value) {
    echo $value."<br/>"; 
}
```

**Result:**

```
Wii
Playstation 3
Xbox
Dator
```

Also note that, `while($console <5){` this condition will make your loop to infinite, if you still want to use `while()` loop than you can check other answer or you can follow this example also.

**[From the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php):**

```
<?php
$console = array("Wii","Playstation 3","Xbox","Dator");
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($console) ) 
    echo $val."<br/>"; 
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Wii
Playstation 3
Xbox
Dator
```

*You can also explore the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php*

Answer (score 1):

For the loop to be dynamic, you need to `count()` the amount of items in the array and the use a counter variable (`$x` in this instance) to output each iteration of the array.

```
<?php 

$console = array("Wii","Playstation 3","Xbox","Dator");
echo "I like " .$console[0] . " and " . $console[1] . ".";

$x=0;

while($x < count($console)){
echo "The console you like is: ". $console[$x] ."<br>";
$x++;
}


?>
```

Read more at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 1):

As you need to write / show all the values from the array using the while loop, you need the total number of count values and a counter. The counter track the array pointer and inside the while loop you need to increment it.

```
$console = array("Wii","Playstation 3","Xbox","Dator");
//echo "I like " .$console[0] . " and " . $console[1] . ".";
$count = count($console);
$counter = 0

while($counter <= $count){
    echo "The console you like is: ". $console[$counter]." <br>";
    $counter++;
}
```

You can use the `foreach(){}` while will perform better for this type of array.